# Efficient Search Query in Elastic for Multiple Exact String

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I want to search for a some (about 50 string) in all document in elasticsearch node , strings in array contain space and special character . i have text filed in all document stored in elastic search , some thing like below :

```
{"mid": 579820586177,
"text": "If you read and listen to",
}
{"mid": 579820586178,
"text": "two articles every day, your reading and",
}
{"mid": 579820586179,
"text": "You can learn quickly and after some time you will not have",
}
```

array of string like

```
["listen to","two articles","some time"]
```

i use elastic query like below but i recive too slow response

```
"query_string": {
  "query": "text:\"\%listen to\%\" OR text:\"\%two articles\%\" OR text:\"\%some time\%\"",
  "analyze_wildcard": true
}
```

what is the efficient query for 10M document and about 50 word.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something obvious , you can use wildcard query like this  -

```
  {
    "query": {
    "bool": {
         "should": [{
                  "wildcard": {
                     "text": {
                        "value": "listen to"
                     }
                  }
               },
               {
                  "wildcard": {
                     "text": {
                        "value": "two articles"
                     }
                  }
               }
         ],
        "minimum_should_match":1

      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: it's return all documents

Comment: try using must instead of should

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand you correct, but noticing where you put your wildcards, this is where the phrase queries are build for. If you are looking in the text for two words that should be in the text in that order, the phrase query is where to go. Below an example of how to use and a link for more information.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "phrase": {
            "text": "listen to"
          }
        },
        {
          "phrase": {
            "text": "two articles"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase.html